No module named "clr_loader" when importing pythonnet/clr
I am trying to use pythonnet, and to do so import clr to run the following script:
import clr
import sys

# Add reference to a simple .NET assembly
clr.AddReference("System")
from System import String

print(String.Format("Hello, {0}!", "World"))

and i get the following:
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File ~\anaconda3\envs\monsterscope_24\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\py3compat.py:356 in compat_exec
    exec(code, globals, locals)

  File c:\users\picke\documents\aa_amy\flexiscope python scripts\stepper stage control - python\untitled0.py:8
    import clr

  File ~\anaconda3\envs\monsterscope_24\lib\site-packages\clr.py:5
    from pythonnet import load

  File ~\anaconda3\envs\monsterscope_24\lib\site-packages\pythonnet\__init__.py:6
    import clr_loader

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'clr_loader'

pip install clr-loader doesn't work, in that I can install the module but it doesnt resolve the error, but I can't find anything about this online.
pip install pythonnet
Requirement already satisfied: pythonnet in c:\users\picke\anaconda3\envs\monsterscope_24\lib\site-packages (3.0.3)
Requirement already satisfied: clr-loader<0.3.0,>=0.2.6 in c:\users\picke\anaconda3\envs\monsterscope_24\lib\site-packages (from pythonnet) (0.2.6)
Requirement already satisfied: cffi>=1.13 in c:\users\picke\anaconda3\envs\monsterscope_24\lib\site-packages (from clr-loader<0.3.0,>=0.2.6->pythonnet) (1.15.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pycparser in c:\users\picke\anaconda3\envs\monsterscope_24\lib\site-packages (from cffi>=1.13->clr-loader<0.3.0,>=0.2.6->pythonnet) (2.21)
Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.

pip install clr-loader
Requirement already satisfied: clr-loader in c:\users\picke\anaconda3\envs\monsterscope_24\lib\site-packages (0.2.6)
Requirement already satisfied: cffi>=1.13 in c:\users\picke\anaconda3\envs\monsterscope_24\lib\site-packages (from clr-loader) (1.15.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pycparser in c:\users\picke\anaconda3\envs\monsterscope_24\lib\site-packages (from cffi>=1.13->clr-loader) (2.21)
Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.

pip install clr_loader
Requirement already satisfied: clr_loader in c:\users\picke\anaconda3\envs\monsterscope_24\lib\site-packages (0.2.6)
Requirement already satisfied: cffi>=1.13 in c:\users\picke\anaconda3\envs\monsterscope_24\lib\site-packages (from clr_loader) (1.15.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pycparser in c:\users\picke\anaconda3\envs\monsterscope_24\lib\site-packages (from cffi>=1.13->clr_loader) (2.21)
Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.


pip install clr-loader` doesn't work -- What does that mean?  That IS the correct solution.  You'll need to do that in the Anaconda environment.

what means "pip install clr-loader doesn't work"? If you get error then show it in question (not in comments) as text (not image).

Sorry let me rephrase in the original question
